# Flutter Notification OneSignal - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, flutter-dependencies

After 1 pm today (19/03/2020) I can't compile my Flutter application anymore. Yesterday I followed all the steps in the documentation (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup) and it had worked perfectly. My version of the fluter is as follows and the onesignal:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.18363.720], locale pt-BR)
onesignal_flutter: ^2.3.4
```

Shows the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.11.2,3.99.99] as no versions of com.onesignal:OneSignal are available.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find any matches for com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.11.2,3.99.99] as no versions of com.onesignal:OneSignal are available.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :onesignal_flutter

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue from 5 hours. I think the package onesignal_flutter is temporarily crashed or something.

Comment: I just disabled the package and removed its lines from its affected files, and my project is working

Answer (score 4):

Updating onesignal in app/build.gradle seems to fix it

```
dependencies {
   // (OLD) implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.4, 3.99.99'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.7'
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @user3136059, this solution is worked for me.